# Write null despite NullValueHandling.Ignore

Tags: c#, json.net

Usually I don't want to write `null` in my JSON. That's why I set `NullValueHandling` in `JsonSerializerSettings` to `NullValueHandling.Ignore`. However, in a few cases I would like to write `null` nonetheless. How can I do that?

Comment: please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override it on a per property basis - add the following attribute to your properties:

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]
```